# Firebase cloud function error, how to debug?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

For some reason about a couple week ago, notifications in my app stopped working. I'm looking in the Firebase console through the logs of the function responsible for sending notifications and I see this:

[image: log]

However, I don't see where I can actually see the error that happened. Are the error logs located somewhere?

Comment: You are looking at the error logs.

Comment: ok, is there a way to see what went wrong?

Comment: If that's the only thing in your log, then that's all you have to work with.  To be honest, it doesn't even really look like an error.

Comment: It literally says "Error" when I hover over the triangle

Comment: That's because whatever logged that message logged it at "error" level.  Go find the line of code that logged it and work backward from there.

Comment: This means that the code called `console.error()` somewhere. It's impossible to say where that happened from the information you shared.

Comment: So it looks like I'm getting an error: `Cannot read property 'packId' of undefined` at `const packId = event.params.packId;`

Comment: Did you perhaps upgrade to Cloud Functions 1.0.x?  There was an [change to the API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff#event_parameter_split_into_data_and_context), with `event` replaced by `data` and `context`.